# if $p(x)$ is irreducible show $cp(x)$ also is irreducible

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

If $p(x)$ is irreducible in $K[x]$ and $c \ne 0$, $c \in K$ $\Rightarrow cp(x)$ is irreducible in  $K[x]$.

I would start saying that $p(x)=a(x)b(x)$ with $a(x)$ a unit $\lambda \in K$, 
without loss of generality,

$\Rightarrow p(x)=\lambda b(x)$  $\Rightarrow cp(x)=(c\lambda) b(x)$, because     $c \lambda \in K \Rightarrow cp(x)$ is irreducible.

I'm not sure if it shows the statement.

Comment: What is $K$? ${}$

Comment: the set that contains the coefficients for the polynomials.

Comment: Yeah but is it an integral domain, a field, etc.?

Comment: an Integral domain.

Comment: If $K$ is an integral domain and not a field then the statement is not true. Take $x \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, it is irreducible but $2x$ is not.

Comment: @AnuragA depends on the definition of irreducibility in $K[x]$. I've seen the (absolutely godawful) definition that a *polynomial* is irreducible if it doesn't factor as the product of two *positive degree* polynomials.

Comment: @jgon you are correct but I was going with the standard one.

Comment: That being said, I haven't finished reading the question to see if I can tell which the OP is using. Sure, I prefer the standard one too, but it doesn't help a person who uses the other definition.

Comment: The definition I use is that $p(x)$ is irreducible in $K[x]$ if whenever $p(x)=a(x)b(x) \Rightarrow$ $a(x)$ or $b(x)$ is a unit

Answer (score 1):

Your proof doesn't show the claimed statement.

First of all your proof basically goes: We can write $p(x)=\lambda b(x)$ with $\lambda$ a unit in $K$, $b(x)=\newcommand{\inv}{^{-1}}\lambda\inv p(x)$. Then you write $cp(x)=(c\lambda) b(x)$ and claim that this implies that $cp(x)$ is irreducible. But this doesn't follow. It's essentially circular, you don't know that $b(x)$ or $(c\lambda) b(x)$ are irreducible without using this lemma in the first place.

Also as pointed out in the comments, depending on your definition of irreducible, this statement may be false.

Also the choice of $K$ to represent an integral domain is less than ideal. $K,L,M$ are usually reserved for fields. More common for integral domains are either $A,B,\ldots$ or $R,S,T,\ldots$.